# Setenv in bash when I compile on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, environment, netcdf

When I was installing Netcdf,
The code below was clipped from install guide:

```
setenv DIR path_to_directory/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES
setenv CC gcc
setenv CXX g++
setenv FC gfortran
setenv FCFLAGS -m64
setenv F77 gfortran
setenv FFLAGS -m64
```

I was using bash.

#### 1. I tried:

```
F77 = "gfortran"
export F77
```

But

> -bash: F77: command not found

#### 2. When I tried：

export F77=gfortran

It didn't work. Because when I use `which F77`, it didn't showed `/usr/bin/gfortran`

#### 3. I also tried:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
# edit these variable in
source ~/.bash_profile
```

The result:

```
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/pgi': not a valid identifier
```

Every method has failed. Can some one offer some help?

Comment: "Because when I use which F77, it didn't showed /usr/bin/gfortran": You get variable value by `$variablename`, not `variablename`. So `which $F77` would work.

Comment: The bash syntax to set a variable is `F77=gfortran`, without spaces. `F77 = gfortran` invokes the command `F77` (which doesn't exist), passing it two arguments: `=` and `gfortran`. Similarly, in the export command, the assignment must not have spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

`which F77` looks for the literal command `F77`.  You need to do `which gofortran` to find where the `gofortran` command is, and then you need to `export F77=/path/to/gofortran`.

F77 is a variable that should contain text, so you can also do `which $F77` to see the location of the binary **in the F77** variable.